# php - Is array_slice safe to use on associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Associative array elements are implicitly ordered.

As far as I know regarding their analogue in JS (objects) there are no guarantees about the element order.

`array_slice` is a function dependent on the elements order.

Is it safe to assume that the result of array_slice will be consistent with the order an associative array will be iterated in using a `foreach` statement ?

Comment: @cale_b Testing is not a guarantee. I tried it on my setup before I asked. It worked as expected.  Even if I tested it on multiple different setups it would not be a guarantee still. Your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: Here is a sample code. `$arr = ['s' => 1, 'r' => 2,  'd' => 3, 't' ]; var_dump(array_slice($arr, -2)); `. Even if I created a phpunit test to automatically generate  random arrays with millions of values and to compare their order before and after array_slice. Even if I ran it on thousand different setups it would still be pointless when it is not documented. Thank God it is mentioned in the PHP docs. The accepted answers still fails to mention the documentation.

Comment: You're missing my point: Put it in your _question_ - next time it'll be better received, because you've shown your research more clearly.

Comment: You are right. I will take more effort writing my questions the next time. Thanks for the suggestion !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's arrays and Javascript's objects are not comparable.

PHP's arrays are *ordered, associative* data structures. Javascript doesn't have any equivalent to that.* PHP's arrays aren't *implicitly* ordered, they're *explicitly* ordered. That applies to both numeric and string keys.

Yes, `array_slice` is safe to use on them. Note that it has an explicit `$preserve_keys` parameter which you must set to `true` if you want to keep your arrays associative; otherwise they will be re-indexed numerically.

<sub>* Javascript only has fundamentally *unordered, associative* objects. Recent ECMAScript versions specify *some* ordering for them, but it's not really controllable by the user. Javascript's `Array` adds a usage pattern on top of those unordered objects which lets you have *ordered, but non-associative* data structures.</sub>